# Added Keys in the dictionary stored in the correct order

Tags: python

I would like to add other keys (digits in sequence) to individual values in the dictionary describing favorite cities. For example, I would like to add the cities Hamburg and Dortmund to viktor which will keep the order of keys 3,4. Unfortunately, the keys are overwritten giving this result:

```
Favorite cities: Viktor
1, Dortmund
2, Dresden
0, Hamburg
```

---

```
dict={"Viktor":{1:"Berlin",2:"Dresden"},"Joe":{1:"London",2:"Liverpool"}}

name=input("What is your name? ").title()
if name not in dict:
  print("You are not in the database.")
  exit()
q = input("Enter how many your favorite cities you want to add ")
if q.isdigit():
  q = int(q)
  for d in range(q):
    fav_city = input("Enter your favorite city: ")
    dict[name][d] = fav_city
    print(fav_city, "added")

  for person, city in dict.items():
    print(f"Favorite cities: {person}")
    for nummer, city1 in city.items():
      print(f"{nummer}, {city1}\n")
else:
  print("Enter a digit!")
  exit()
```

Comment: `for d in range(q)` will iterate starting from 0 up to `q-1`. Any keys present in the dictionary will be overwritten. Find the `max` key first, `max(dict[name])` and then add `d + 1` to that value. Or choose a better data structure.

Comment: Note also that `dict` is the name of a built-in Python function, which you are overwriting by using it as a variable name. It's bad practice to do so, and can lead to annoying/difficult to find bugs. Use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Why not use a `list` for the favorite cities? There's an inherent order to lists via their indices. It can easily be added to, removed from, shuffled, inserted into, etc.

Comment: When printing a person's favorite cities, you can even show the ordering by using `for num, city in enumerate(cities)` to show the "rank" of each city according to that person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is causing the problem here.

```
for d in range(q)
```

This kind of construction will have d start at the value 0 and continue until (q-1).

What you want is to start counting from the existing length of your persons city dictionary and increment q times. You can get that length using the len() function and then structure the for loop in the following way:

```
my_city_len = len(dict[name])
for d in range(my_city_len, my_city_len + q)
```

You also should take into account that your dictionary keys start counting from 1 and not from 0 and so you have to add 1 to d.

In the end, the looping should looks something like this:

```
my_city_len = len(dict[name])
for d in range(my_city_len, my_city_len + q):
    fav_city = input("Enter your favorite city: ")
    dict[name][d+1] = fav_city
    print(fav_city, "added")
```

Answer (score 1):

this guide should work for you https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/change-the-key-in-a-dictionary-in-python/

the idea here is that you should have a function to change all the dictionary keys that comes after the one you need to add BEFORE you add it;
first you shift all the keys after with a for loop and second you add the new key